# Node.js - What does the "(0)" mean at the end of an function

Tags: node.js, function

A few weeks ago i started learning Node.js. In the examples of code i use to get familiar with the language, i sometimes see functions getting closed with ")(0);" instead of ");". Does anyone know what the (0) means? I personally think it has something to do with an exit status but i'm not sure because i can't seem to find anything about it on the internet.

In the code down here i pasted a part of the code with a function of the code where i have this question about.

```
            (function iterator(index) {
            if (index == files.length) {
                self._photos = only_files;
                callback(null, self.photos);
                return;
            }

            fs.stat(
                self.path + "/" + files[index],
                function (err, stats) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback({ error: "file_error",
                                   message: JSON.stringify(err) });
                        return;
                    }
                    if (stats.isFile()) {
                        only_files.push(files[index]);
                    }
                    iterator(index + 1)
                }
            );
        })(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). It tells the function to execute immediately, and then is passing 0 to the `index` parameter.

You can see an example in your console by pasting:

```
(function iterator(index) {
    console.log(index);
})(5);
```

Enter anything in the `()` to see the output!

Comment: Thank you very much! That 0 makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

It's an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) taking a parameter of `0`.

Here it's also named `iterator`, you're essentially calling `iterate(0)`.